# The c++ standard documentation says a program shall not call the main function, but I did

Tags: c++, recursion, program-entry-point

It explicitly says in the c++ standard documentation that a program may not call main. Yet I wrote a program that calls main and works perfectly fine, why is that? The code:

```
#include<iostream>

static int counter = 0;

int main(){
    counter++;
    std::cout << counter << " It works" << std::endl;
    
    while(counter < 10){
        main();
    }

    return 1;
}
```

It prints to console "It works" 10 times. According to the standard documentation, this should not work, yet it works. What's going on?

Comment: undefined behavior means whatever you get is "correct".  In C++, if you break the rules, it doesn't necessarily mean the program wont compile.

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation? I believe this is just undefined behavior.

Comment: @Orace https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function  what exactly does undefined behavior mean?

Comment: Think this through if the program would really have worked you would have seen a whole lot more "It works"... and then a stackoverflow (infinite recursion). So does it really work? (The program really shows undefined behavior)

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144030/why-calling-main-is-not-allowed-in-c

Comment: Undefined behavior means that really anything could happen, including seemingly working fine. It might also cause crashes, [summon nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html), or cause your pets to spontaneously combust. Also see e.g. [How undefined is undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961067/how-undefined-is-undefined-behavior)

Comment: While this is UB, "shall not" in the standard typically means that you'll get a diagnostic of some kind, which doesn't happen here.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, I see. That clarification might be worth adding to your answer then, especially since the question explicitly mentions that they expect a diagnostic.

Comment: I get compilation errors with clang and gcc - live - https://godbolt.org/z/3dzf9vTGM

Comment: Undefined behavior means the programmer messed up, and did something in violation to C++ standard.  C++ is not a nanny language, and gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`basic.start.main/3`](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#3.sentence-1):
*The function `main` shall not be used within a program.*

Violating this rule makes your program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) - which means that the program can do pretty much anything. It may even do what you wanted it to do or appear to do what you wanted but have devastating side effects, so avoid having *undefined behavior* in your programs.

Regarding the lack of diagnostic messages: I suspect that some compilers, like g++, actually support calling `main` as an extension. I had to turn on `-pedantic` or `-pedantic-errors` to get the diagnostic message "*ISO C++ forbids taking address of function '::main' [-Wpedantic]*"