# Recursive call on main C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can main function call itself in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c)

I found this problem very interesting but illusive a bit.
Question 6.42 C++ how to program by Dietel "Can main be called recursively on your system? write a program containing a function main. Include Static local variable count and initialize to 1. Post-increment and print the value of count each time main is called. Compile your program. What happens ?

I wrote the program as below but instead I made the recursion stops after 10 times as if I were to keep it running it will stops at a value around 41000.

my question: how is it legal to call recursively main function in c++, should this program be executed to stack over flow or memory fault, etc.. ? Please explain.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
       static int count = 0;
       count++;
       if(count <= 10) {
                cout << count << endl;
                return main(); //call main
                }//end if

       system("pause");
       return 0;//successful completion
}//end main
```

thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How is it legal to call the `main()` function recursively in C++

It is not legal.  The C++ language standard states that "The function main shall not be used within a program" (C++11 §3.6.1/3).  Calling the function is a form of "use."

Any program that calls `main()` exhibits undefined behavior (technically, such a program is ill-formed because the rule being violated is a diagnosable semantic rule, though I'd be surprised if most compilers rejected the program).  Note that this does not prevent the runtime infrastructure that starts your program from calling the `main()` function.

Comment: I think it also helps to quote the more human-readable, but less general "Recursive calls are permitted, except to the function named main" from §5.2.2[expr.call]/9

Comment: @James, thank you for your reply - if the C++ standard states the above - so why the recursive call is permitted by compilers. I found behavior weird to comprehend. I would appreciate your reply.

Comment: I cannot answer that for all compilers, since I am only very familiar with one (Visual C++) and somewhat familiar with a few others.  However, I would hazard to guess that `main()` is just treated by the compiler like any other function.  On Windows, `main()` is not the entry point called by the OS:  it couldn't be, because the C runtime has to do work to initialize globals and prepare the environment for execution. After it does this, the C runtime calls your program's `main()`. So, it really is just another function, but _you_ are not allowed to call it, only the C runtime may call it.

Comment: Thank you James, that explains alot.

Comment: @Sinan: Undefined behavior is a get out of jail free card to compiler vendors. It means vendors have free reign to do whatever they want and still be compliant with the standard. Many vendors use a common framework for their C and C++ compilers. The C standard requires vendors to provide the ability to call `main` recursively. The easiest thing to do is to extend that capability to C++. That's OK by the C++ standard. Calling main recursively in C++ might work on your computer with your compiler because of this. That does not mean it will work when you switch computers / switch compilers.