# Return of my program isn't functioning as intended

Tags: c++

I'm having a really weird problem I can't seem to nail down. I need to provide a way to step back from one menu to the previous menu, my program does this, however once I have entered the secondary menu which I have programmed as a function when I step back to the previous menu in the main function it requires that you select the quit option in the first menu twice before the program actually returns 0 and prompts to close the console. I understand that my code is messy right now, because I am in the middle of putting things together and I am still learning. It does not have any critical errors (compiles and runs in my intended output excepting the issue stated), It does contain a few warnings (most of which will be corrected when I finish it) I have not tried using global variables because everyone seems to hate them, but I am wondering if global variables are required for concurrency between methods when not using pointers (something I have not learned how to use yet). I am only asking for an explaination of what I have done wrong and what I can do to fix it.

My code for the main function.

`````
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;
int countBySheet();
int main()
{

    int choice;

    cout << "Express estimator" << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "1. Count by Sheet (eg. Lighting, Service, Site Lighting, Power)" << endl;
    cout << "2. Count by Category (eg. Building, HVAC, Large Circuits, Service, Site Lighting)" << endl;
    cout << "3. Quit Program" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
        switch(choice) {

            case 1: cout << "Count by Sheet" << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            cout << choice << " is the value of the CHOICE variable" << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            countBySheet();
            break;
            case 2: cout << "Count by Category" << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            cout << choice << " is the value of the CHOICE variable" << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            //create count by category function
            break;
            case 3: cout << "Quit program" << endl;
            return 0;

            }
            if(choice =1){ main();}
            else if (choice =2) {main();}
                else if (choice=3) {return 3;}
// I originally had one else if statement and allowed the console to terminate from the return statement included in case 3, this produced the explained effect after I chose case 1 or case 2 first, I then added the second else if statement with a return 0 and the explained effect continued, I changed the return statement to 3 to see if that would make a difference, it does not.
            }````

My code for the Secondary function.
`````

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;
int main();
int countBySheet()
{

int choice;

cout << "By Sheet" << endl;
cout << " " << endl;
cout << " " << endl;
cout << " " << endl;
cout << "1. Lighting Plan" << endl;
cout << "2. Power Plan" << endl;
cout << "3. Service plan" << endl;
cout << "4. Site plan" << endl;
cout << "5. Back" << endl;
cin >> choice;
    switch(choice) {

        case 1: cout << "Lighting Plan" << endl;
        //create count by sheet function
        break;
        case 2: cout << "Power Plan" << endl;
        //create count by category function
        break;
        case 3: cout << "Service Plan" << endl;
        break;
        case 4: cout << "Site Plan" << endl;
        break;
        case 5: cout << "Back" << endl;

        return main();

        }
        if(choice =1){ countBySheet();}
        else if (choice =2) {countBySheet();}

        }
```

Comment: You can't recursively call `main`

Comment: `if(choice =1)` is always true because it is doing an assignment.  Use `if (choice == 1)` instead.

Comment: As noted by @cigien, calling [`main` is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349515/recursive-call-on-main-c). However, this likely isn't the source of whatever issue you're encountering since most implementations don't behave unreasonably when `main` is called.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and flag them to be treated as fatal errors (because that's exactly what they are). They should be telling you several important things.

Comment: @WhozCraig I will definitely do that when I get further along and feel like my program is close to alpha ready, but for now I allow it to compile with warnings because I am very new and want to write a little then test for proper function, I use things like un-used variables and functions instead as my TODO instead of commenting one out. this way when I correct it, I have only typed what I need and deleted nothing to show that it has been finished and corrected. idk if it actually saves time, but it feels like it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your functions recursively, while actually, what you want to do is calling them in a loop. Basic pattern:

```
while(true) {
  cin >> choice;
  switch(choice) {
    case 1: doSomething(); break;
    case 2: return 0;   // NOT return main()!
  }
  // no "if (choice == 1)" with recursion back into the same function.
  // Processing resumes at the top of the while loop. 
}
```

But more specifically to your question: `return main();` calls another "instance" of the main menu, and *then* returns once that has ended. At that point it will return to `main()` (the calling function), which is exactly the behavior you are seeing: You need to quit the main menu, twice.

Forget about concurrency. There is none in your program.