# Why does the next line of a function still execute despite calling another function before such line?

Tags: c++

Here's a sample code where it is evident:

```
int foo();
void bar();

bool flag = false;

int foo()
{
    if(!flag) bar();
    cout<<"Reached Here!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void bar()
{
    flag = true;
    foo();
}
```

In this code, `cout<<"Reached Here!"<<endl;` is executed twice. However, simulating it step-by-step does not agree with that. From what I am expecting, it should go like this:

1. Since `!flag` is true, call `bar()`
2. From function `bar()`, set `flag = true`
3. Then, call `foo()`
4. Since `!flag` is now false, we just proceed to next line
5. Output `Reached Here` to console
6. End of Program

As you can see, I am expecting for `cout<<"Reached Here!"<<endl;` to only be executed once. So, why is it being executed twice and how can I avoid that (aside from enclosing the next lines with `else`)?

Edit: Changed `foo()` to `bar()` and changed `main()` to `foo()`

Comment: Recursive call of `main()` is illegal in C++. [Recursive call on main C++ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349515/recursive-call-on-main-c)

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Pretty futile to ask about how that will behave.

Comment: `main` is rather special, you can do `int main() { my_main(); }` and call `my_main` recursively

Comment: Regardless of the undefined behavior of calling main, I don't know why you expect it to only print once. `if (condition) { A; } B;` will execute `A` followed by `B` if the condition is true, and will execute only `B` if the condition is false.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm only calling main for the sake of this example. Just think of it like some other function for now.... (nevermind I'll just edit that out lol)

Comment: Please edit the question to have `main` call a separate function that does this logic and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: `bar` should call `foo` now instead of `main`?

Comment: Yes. And it still have the same behavior as with any other function names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you *return* from functions, the execution continues from the line after the function call. This is what *return* means.

Therefore, the actual trace is:

1. (1st call of) `foo()` calls `bar()`, seeing `flag = false`
2. `bar()` sets `flag = true`
3. `bar()` calls (2nd) `foo()`
4. (2nd call of) `foo()` skips `bar()`, seeing `flag = true`
5. (2nd call of) `foo()` prints "Reached Here!"
6. (2nd call of) `foo()` returns zero to `bar()`
7. `bar()` returns
8. (1st call of) `foo()` prints "Reached Here!"
9. (1st call of) `foo()` returns zero to its caller