# Calling the main function in C++ is ignored using CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, codeblocks, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can main function call itself in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c)

I decided to do a small test using CodeBlock IDE by calling the main function which should be an illegal act.

EX:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout<<"hello"<<endl;
  main();
  return 0;
}
```

Strangely, in code blocks I was able to compile this mess. Does anyone know why?

Output: hello

Comment: CodeBlocks is an IDE not a compiler. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Why do you think it is illegal to call `main` from `main`?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: because the language specification doesn't allow that (i.e calling `main()` explicitly from your code; only the runtime can call it.).

Comment: @Nawaz: I did not know that :-S ... I've seen a couple of *sample* code which do something of that sort. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's using GNU GCC compiler/MinGW.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said in your question itself that calling `main()` explicitly from your code is forbidden by the language specification. Only the runtime can call it.

As you use GCC to compile your code (read your comment), the `-pedantic` option would give you appropriate diagnostic in the form of error or warning. So try this:

```
g++ program.cpp -pedantic
```

Comment: i just wonder how i configure for codeblock?

Comment: @mekici: Sorry, I cannot help you in that, as I've no experience with CodeBlock. Google may help you, though. :-)

Comment: There're too many. I used Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, and sometime [Vim (graphical one)](http://www.vim.org/download.php) with MinGW (on Windows, of course). You can also see [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: ok I find it you can edit this your answer, for codeblock, Settings=>Compiler Settings => check checkbox which write -pedantic

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<"hello"<<endl;
**main();**
return 0;
```

The second line main() will cause an infinite recursive loop with the main() function calling itself again and again, this in turn will cause no path in your code return value.

Since not all paths are returning values, no C compiler will compile this. Forget C, even C# compiler halts when it finds that all paths are not returning a value, though the code is legible.

Comment: The strange thing is that it does not even create the sensible recursive loop.

Comment: Thats because you used the GCC compiler which has its own rules, or perhaps it wants you, the programmer to take care of these things. Try with a Microsoft compiler - you won't be able to do it.

Comment: Update: Just out of curiosity, I tried compiling your code with both MinGW and the Microsoft CL compilers. As expected, MinGW compiled it, but cl threw this error: d:\source\c\test.cpp(9) : warning C4717: 'main' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe 
test.obj

Comment: It seems to me like the Microsoft Compiler is best to work with.

Comment: I think its a bit unfair, basing your opinion on just this one aspect. Remember that gcc is free+open-source and also cross-compiles on linux platform. Moreover, If you have written good ANSI C/C++ code, show me a compiler that refuses to compile that!

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function under main function.main is also a function which is trigger in runtime by complier. Yes it is illegal act but you can call main function under main.To call main function under main cause recessive and run infinitely time. In VS2008 you will get a warning to call main function but the program runs without any problem .

Comment: So why would this compiler or IDE not warn me of such imminent danger? Even beyond that, why would it completely omit the line of code calling the main function to product the output of : "hello"?