# Autoreconf better way to find Boost::Date-time

Tags: boost, autotools, autoconf

I am trying to compile some code using autotools and am getting stuck when trying to include boost::date-time and boost::regex. I was given an `configure.in` file that defines that looks for boost::date-time this way

```
AC_CHECK_LIB(boost_date_time-gcc-mt, main, , [
        AC_CHECK_LIB(boost_date_time-mt, main, , [
                AC_CHECK_LIB(boost_date_time, main, , [
                        AC_MSG_ERROR("Linking against boost::date-time library failed.")])
        ])
])
```

which appears to be the standard way according to google. But when I run autoreconf:

```
$ autoreconf -f -s -i
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in `.'.
libtoolize: linking file `./ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: Consider adding `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])' to configure.in and
libtoolize: rerunning libtoolize, to keep the correct libtool macros in-tree.
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
```

and ./configure:

```
$ CXXFLAGS="-g -w" ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PATH
...
checking for main in -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt... no
checking for main in -lboost_date_time-mt... no
checking for main in -lboost_date_time... no
configure: error: "Linking against boost::date-time library failed."
```

It cannot be found. I know they are there cause I compiled boost 1.53 from scratch. What could be an issue here?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are macros at the [GNU Autoconf Archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/) for both [boost::date-time](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_date_time.html#ax_boost_date_time) and [boost::regex](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_boost_regex.html#ax_boost_regex).  Perhaps they would be more suitable.

> It cannot be found. I know they are there cause I compiled boost 1.53 from scratch. What could be an issue here?

You'll have to consult `config.log` to know that for sure. Since you are looking for the `main` functions in those libs (which aren't in those libs, but that's another issue), the `AC_CHECK_LIB` tests generate [invalid C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c), and that may be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent [boost.m4](https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4/wiki) macro. You can copy it into a top level `./m4` directory.

- `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` in `configure.ac`
- `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 --install` in the top-level `Makefile.am`
- invoke `aclocal` with `aclocal -I m4 --install`

It's very easy to use the results in `configure.ac`, e.g., for Boost.Filesystem:

```
BOOST_REQUIRE([1.53], [ACTION-IF-NOT-FOUND])
AC_SUBST(BOOST_CPPFLAGS)
MY_PROJECT_CPPFLAGS+="$BOOST_CPPFLAGS"

BOOST_FILESYSTEM([mt])
AC_SUBST(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBS)
AC_SUBST(BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LDFLAGS)
MY_PROJECT_LIBFLAGS+="$BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LDFLAGS $BOOST_FILESYSTEM_LIBS"
```

It will even add dependencies like Boost.System.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. I can use the flags inside the configure.in, but as soon as I try to invoke --with-boost=/path/to/boost it cannot find boost and I am not sure why. Any suggestions?

Comment: @madtowneast - I built boost-1.53 with MacPorts, which places the `boost` directory under: `/opt/local/include` ... that's how it worked for me. The shared libs are under `/opt/local/lib`.