# Program goes into infinite loop in case of wrong input

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to check the input value, and I run this program below. But when I give a wrong input it goes into infinite loop. I tried the `cin.clear();` but still it goes to infinite loop. Please can anyone give me a solution for this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c=0;
    cout<<"in test"<<endl;
    //cin.clear();
    cin>>c;

    if(cin.fail())
        {
            cout<<"please try again"<<endl;
            main();
        }

    else
        cout<<"c = "<<c<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do not explicitly call [`main`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cin.ignore()` after `cin.clear()` to remove the invalid input from stream buffer. Using `cin.clear()` does not remove the previous input, so it keeps going into an infinite loop. `cin.clear()` only resets the state, i.e., the error flags etc.

Try this:

```
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX,'\n');
```

It clears till the first newline is encountered.

Comment: I tried according to your suggestion, but the problem is if i give (for example --- >> an input abcd) it shows please try again for three times. is it possible to clear the wrong input in one time.

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

You cannot call the `main()` function from anywhere within your program.

**Second:**

Try a while loop like this:

```
while (cin.fail())
{
    cout << "Please try again" << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore();
}
```