# Can main() function be called a constructor function

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to know whether `int main()` function be called a constructor function since it nearly works same as a constructor function of a class?

And if yes, then what is the class name it belongs to?

Edit: The reason why I think main() works nearly same as constructor function is that whenever we execute a programme the first thing which gets executed is the main function.. Similarly a constructor function executes first whenever we define a  variable with data type as user defined class

Comment: What...? `main` is not a constructor... not at all...

Comment: No. `int main()` is not a constructor (it doesn't **construct** anything), and it does not belong to any class.

Comment: "Nearly works the same as a constructor" – in what way?  I don't see much in common, but if you explain why you think they're similar, it might help others to explain why they're not.

Comment: Sorry guys, I think this community is not for me. As most of the questions I ask here are either downvoted or not voted at all.. I should just ask to teachers

Answer (score 2):

> Can `main()` function be called a constructor function

No

A class *constructor* is a [*member-funtion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions). A *member function* is **different** from a *non-member function* which `int main()` is.

Actually a Constructor is a special kind of member-function that has no name and no address. This is responsible for creating objects. Objects can be created an "infinite" number of times in your program.

While `main()` is the function that starts up your program and you are [not permitted to call `main()` else you invoke Undefined Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: plus 1 for solid definition of a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

**From [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function):**

`main()` "is a global function named main, which is the designated start of the program".[[1]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)

So it is **not** part of a **class**, not a member method, hence the method **CANNOT** be a **constructor**. Rememember that C++ is a multiparadigm language. It includes an object oriented approach, but it does not need it to function. Java or C# are also multiparadigm, but they are mainly class and OOP based. For instance, in [Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11hello/HelloWorld.java.html) and [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288463(v=vs.71).aspx) you **need** to have **classes** and **objects** to create a "Hello World" program.