# Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'std::string*& {aka std::basic_string<char>*&}' from an rvalue of type 'std::string* {aka

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am trying to solve this question where I have to spell numbers.
When I try to call my array of strings `a` by reference, I get this error. But I get no error if I call it by value.
I don't know where is the rvalue coming from as my string elements should be considered lvalue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void spell(int n,string* &a){
    if(n==0)
    return;
    spell(n/10,a);
    cout<<a[n%10];
}
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    string a[10]{"zero ","one ","two ","three ","four ","five ","six ","seven ","eight ","nine "};
    spell(n,a);
    if(n<0)
    return 0;
    return main();
}
```

Comment: Why do you have *& you are not changing what a is pointing to within that function.

Comment: Unrelated: Rethink `return main();`. I'm not sure what you meant to do here, but calling `main` is illegal.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I was thinking that if the question wanted me to do it for many many integers at once, performing string copy many many times would slow it down

Comment: @AjayTyagiB18ME003, if you pass just a * you are not passing a copy, so there is no overhead there

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know why is it illegal, but I do it everytime when I test my code . I keep giving the inputs, and main repeats until I enter some invalid input ( in this case, negative values)

Comment: @OmidCompSCI Yes, that's right. I don't know why I was thinking of string copies being made

Comment: @AjayTyagiB18ME003 "*I do it everytime when I test my code*" - well, stop doing it. It is *illegal*. Use an ordinary loop instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  Alright, I'll start using loop instead. btw I was waiting to get an error someday.

Comment: [What the C++ Standard has to say about calling `main`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#start.main-3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, [calling `main()` is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/), so `return main();` is *undefined behavior*.  Use a `do..while` loop instead if you want to run `main()`'s code multiple times.

The rvalue the compile is complaining about comes when the `string[]` array [*decays*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/) into a `string*` pointer to the 1st element when passed to `spell()`.  Your declaration of `a` is a non-const lvalue reference, which cannot be bound to an rvalue, hence the compiler error.

`spell()` does not modify `a` itself to point somewhere else, it is only accessing the `string` objects in the array that `a` points to, so there is no need to pass `a` by reference, passing it by value will work just fine:

`void spell(int n, string* a)`

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/gbTR3D)

Or, passing it by `const` reference will also work, since a const lvalue reference can be bound to an rvalue:

`void spell(int n, string* const &a)`

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/G9KlP6)

Comment: @AjayTyagiB18ME003 fixed, I had the `const` in the wrong place