# Extra 444 returned while calling main function recursively?

Tags: c, recursion, static, program-entry-point

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int s;
    ++s;
    printf("%d",s);
    if(s<=3)
        main();
    printf("%d",s);

}
```

I'm getting output `12344444` but need only `12344`. Can anyone please explain why this problem arises and provide solution?

Comment: The last `printf` statement will execute multiple times as the recursion unwinds. You, after all, call `main` multiple times.

Comment: Isn't calling main() undefined behavior?

Comment: It's actually illegal to call `main` recursively.

Comment: @john only in [C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128326/4142924)? The C standard does not mention this.

Comment: @John - not true, although that is the case in C++. Yet another difference between the two languages.

Comment: @Bathsheba OK, I stand corrected, however this question must have been tagged C++ at some point, otherwise I wouldn't have ended up here

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int s;
    ++s;
    printf("%d",s); // this printf is called and will print each
                    // number as the recursion is called down
    if(s<=3)
        main();
    printf("%d",s); // <<-- this is why
                    // this one is called as the recursion functions
                    // return so it will be called with the highest 
                    // number as many times as there were recursion.

}
```

To get what you want try

```
  #include<stdio.h>
    void recursive()
    {
        static int s;
        ++s;
        printf("%d",s); // this printf is called and will print each
                        // number as the recursion is called down
        if(s<=3)
            recursive();
        else 
            printf("%d",s); // call only if s > 3 
    
    }

    int main()
    {
       recursive();
    }
```

Comment: Actually, the value of `s` will *always* be > 3 when the second `printf` statement is encountered. What your comment there should say is "call only if no recursion happened".

Comment: @AdrianMole yes. but I was writing my comment as a logical  compliment of the s<=3 condition :)

Comment: I appreciate that. But the OP's problem was the printing of the three extra `4` values.

Comment: @AdrianMole you win :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo it might be unwise, but not illegal in C. Its legality is implied in "**5.1.2.2.3 Program termination** 1 If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return ***from the initial call*** to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function."

Comment: @WeatherVane Correct - I've removed my comment and upvoted yours. I just browsed through the current C standard and found no support at all for my statement.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I admit I had to too. Would you prefer to me delete the comment?

Comment: Guys leave the info here. :) that way we can all benefit from your research

Comment: @WeatherVane No, your comment is very good and saves people like me (who thought that it _is_ illegal) a lot of time.

Comment: @WeatherVane  And make you guys look like superstars!!! Your response to new information was commendable and should be an example to others.