# How can I initialize a variable but when said function is initiated the value of the variable is not reset?

Tags: c++

I've made this example to show what I'm talking about. I want to know if there is a way to run through main() without resetting value to 0.

```
int main(){

   int value = 0;
   value++;
   cout << value << endl;
   main();
}
```

Comment: Use static int value =0;

Comment: It is illegal to call `main` inside your program, so no.

Comment: _...The main function has several special properties:

1) It cannot be used anywhere in the program
a) in particular, it cannot be called recursively..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: Don't learn C++ writing C programs. C allows recursion to `main`; [C++ does *not*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c).

Answer (score 3):

Before answering the question, your example has two big problems

- Calling, or even taking the address of, `main` is not allowed.
- Your function has infinite recursion which makes your program have undefined behavior.

A different example where `value` is saved between calls could look like this. It uses a `static` variable, initialized to `0` the first time the function is called, and is never initialized again during the program execution.

```
#include <iostream>

int a_function() {
    static int value = 0;
    ++value;
    if(value < 100) a_function();
    return value;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << a_function();   // prints 100
}
```

Comment: Cheers, as I responded to a different comment, I just needed a quick example which gets the idea across, I can see that it's bugging a lot of people. Next time I'll be sure to show a correct example.

Comment: @Toast258 :-) Many of us jump at those things pretty quickly Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the variable `value` local to the `main` function, you can declare it as `static int value = 0;`.

As has been pointed out in various comments though, recursively calling any function without an escape mechanism like you are is a bad idea. Doing it with `main` is <strike>a worse idea still</strike> apparently not even possible.

Comment: Please point out that will work for every function *except* `main`, since that's in the OP's code. It's UB to recursively call `main`.

Comment: static variables in `main` are pointless.  `main` is only ever called once by the OS

Comment: I wouldn't say "not even possible". I don't think many compilers would stop you. It's just not allowed because the standard says so.

Comment: Yes haha, I realise that it is a bad idea, however, I just needed to write a question quickly and just wrote something which would show what I'm talking about. I promise I'm not stupid.