# Stop function from proceeding

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
if (attackShip == true) {
    board[guessRow][guessCol] = "x";
    cout << "Oops, you sunk my ship!" << endl;
    numShips--;
    if (numShips == 0) {
        cout << "Shiver me timbers! You have won!" << endl;
        playAgain();
    }
    system("CLS");
    clearBoard(board, numShips, ships);
```

It's a battleship game, and I want to ask the user if they want to play again when all ships have been sunk. However, the system clears before anything can be done to the input.

Here's my code for `playAgain`:

```
void playAgain() {
    cout << "Play again? (y/n)" << endl;
    string enter = "";
    string yn;
    if (yn == "y") {
        system("CLS");
        main();
    } else if (yn == "n") {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

My guess would be that it takes a "no input" as the input, and just continues the code? I'm not sure though.

Comment: There's no input in your `playAgain` function. If there was it would wait for that input. Calling `main` in a C++ program is undefined behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing to read the input:

```
void playAgain() {
    cout << "Play again? (y/n)" << endl;
    string enter = "";
    string yn;
    cin >> yn; <============
    if (yn == "y") {
        system("CLS");
        main();
    } else if (yn == "n") {
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

And as Retired Ninja mentionel, don't call the `main` method from `playAgain`. Better create another method called say `play` and call play from both `main` and `playAgain`.

Comment: Not a good place to use recursion anyway. After a fun and long day of playing the game, the program will exhaust automatic storage.